# apache solr 6 multiple dataimporthandler

Tags: apache, solr, dataimporthandler

I want to index from two different databases. Therefore I make two data-config.xml files with different names.
I integrate in solrconfig.xml file two requestHandler with DataimportHandler.

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">   
<lst name="defaults">  
  <str name="config">data-config-847.xml</str>
</lst>
```

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport857" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">   
<lst name="defaults">  
  <str name="config">data-config-857.xml</str>
</lst>
```

But it does not function. I did the same configuration in solr 4.7, it function without problem. What ist different between solr 4.7 and solr 6.0? Or how it function?

Comment: How does it not function? Error message? Do neither work or just one of them?

Comment: Only the one with the name "dataimport" is working. In the admin dashboard both dataimporthandlers are listed. But when you click on the handler called "dataimport857" also the "dataimport" is executed.
Furthermore if there is no dataimport-requesthandler with the name "dataimport" an error is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably [SOLR-8993](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8993) affecting new Admin UI.

Workarounds:

- Use legacy Admin UI, accessible through a link on the top of the screen
- Pass **config** value as a URL parameter invoking DIH URL directly and not via Admin UI. The **defaults** section is just that - defaults that can be overridden with URL parameters.